# Sort answer by oldest broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, sorting

The tooltip when hovering mouse over "oldest" says "Sort answers in the order in which they were provided" but today I found this doesn't always work.

> [image: Screenshot showing oldest answer appearing second instead of in first position.]

Is it because I edited my answer and this bumped me back in line? But then shouldn't the answer that was given last, but before my latest edit, be in second position?

[Link to the question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/online-dictionary-where-i-can-search-for-second-half-of-compound-noun/7238#7238)

Comment: The accepted answer is always on-top unless it's self-answered.

Comment: O.K. thanks... MOds please feel free to close.

Comment: I'm not sure though but I *think* that even before falkb's answer got the green check mark, it was sorted as "oldest"... but no way now to make sure. Will keep an eye out in case it recurs.

Comment: @Eugene new answers come in at the top as well (until refresh) if my memory is correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accepted answers (excluding self-accepts) appear at the top in every sort.  This is intentional.  That tab is (literally in code) a secondary sort after accepted answer sorting.

Comment: I can understand the decision to have the accepted answer being promoted but having the "older" hover message showing "Answers is the order they were provided" is a misleading bug. This message should just state the truth.